# Safety and privacy of data on AWS EC2

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, privacy, amazon-ami

I need to copy highly sensitive data on an AWS EC2 instance (to perform a couple of operations on it.

How safe is my data? (Although I have implemented the security group on this instance; which allows access only from my IP).

**Can Amazon access this data?** Can they somehow **access and use this data**? Since the data involves source code which is extremely crucial to my organization, leaking of which can cause huge repercussions !!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2):

According to Amazon:

**Who owns customer contents?**

Customers maintain ownership of their customer content and select which AWS services process, store and host their customer content. We do not access or use customer content for any purpose other than as legally required and for maintaining the AWS services and providing them to our customers and their end users. We never use customer content or derive information from it for marketing or advertising.

You can also check  [Whitepaper on EU Data Protection](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_EU_Data_Protection_Whitepaper.pdf)
Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you send your data to the Cloud, there are security risks.  There is no way to make these risks zero.

You say you have limited access to your server to just your IP. OK, is it a company IP? Are there others on your Wifi network who connect to the internet with that IP? Is your Wifi network secure? Have any of your employees installed malware on their desktops? etc etc etc. Restricting to your IP only is a good thing to do, but it's not 100% unless you are connecting from a highly secure location.

Amazon says "We do not access or use customer content for any purpose other than as legally required and for maintaining the AWS services and providing them to our customers and their end users." OK, so they CAN access your data.  Who knows what "legally required" means. Seems to me governments are making the laws up as they go along nowadays.

If the data is really that sensitive, don't put it in the Cloud. A cost analysis should help you - how much do you lose if your data is compromised? how much would it cost to buy the server out of the Cloud and do it securely at your company? If the first amount is massive and the second tiny don't use the Cloud!

Comment: Thanks for the answer